# Are there any APIs added for Spotlight Search for iPhone 3.0?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Apple has added Spotlight to OS3.0 release.  I am having problem finding any API for third party apps to work with Spotlight Search.  Is such a thing available?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no third-party APIs for Spotlight Search in iPhone OS 3.0.

Comment: This should be filed as a bug.